# ORACLE ORA-00600: internal error code [24106], [24125], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, oracle11gr2, ora-00600

ORA-00600 appears while executing scheduled SAS job with code:

```
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO MA_CDM.CI_CONTACT_HISTORY ch USING
  (
    SELECT
      VC.CONTACT_ID,
      CASE CNTRL_GRP_FLG
        WHEN 1
        THEN '_20'
        WHEN 0
        THEN '_03'
      END AS STATUS
    FROM
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          COMMUNICATION_SK
        FROM
          SAS_USER.resp_mp_1781661608
      )
      MPC
    INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT
          CONTACT_ID,
          COMMUNICATION_SK,
          CNTRL_GRP_FLG
        FROM
          MA_CDM.V_CONTACT
        WHERE
          STATUS_CD = 'New'
      )
      VC
    ON
      (
        MPC.COMMUNICATION_SK = VC.COMMUNICATION_SK
      )
  )
  t ON
  (
    ch.CONTACT_ID = t.CONTACT_ID
  )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    ch.UPDATE_DATE               = sysdate,
    ch.CONTACT_HISTORY_STATUS_CD = t.STATUS;
  MERGE INTO MA_CDM.CI_CONTACT_HISTORY ch USING
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      vc.CONTACT_ID,
      st.CONTACT_HISTORY_STATUS_CD AS STATUS
    FROM
      SAS_USER.resp_mp_1781661608 mpc
    INNER JOIN MA_CDM.V_CONTACT vc
    ON
      (
        mpc.communication_sk = vc.communication_sk
      AND mpc.CLIENT_OW_ID   = vc.CLIENT_OW_ID
      )
    INNER JOIN MA_CDM.CI_CONTACT_HISTORY_STATUS st
    ON
      trim(UPPER(mpc.EVENT_TYPE)) = trim(UPPER(st.CONTACT_HISTORY_STATUS_DESC))
  )
  t ON
  (
    ch.CONTACT_ID = t.CONTACT_ID
  )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    ch.UPDATE_DATE               = sysdate,
    ch.CONTACT_HISTORY_STATUS_CD = t.STATUS;

  INSERT
  INTO
    MA_CDM.CI_RESPONSE_HISTORY rh
    (
      CELL_PACKAGE_SK ,
      TREATMENT_SK ,
      TREATMENT_HASH_VAL ,
      RESPONSE_SK ,
      CLIENT_OW_ID ,
      RESPONSE_DTTM ,
      RESPONSE_CHANNEL_CD ,
      INFERRED_RESPONSE_FLG ,
      RESPONSE_VALUE_AMT ,
      RESPONSE_DT ,
      RESPONSE_TRACKING_CD ,
      PROCESSED_DTTM ,
      COMMENTS ,
      EXPORTED_FLG
    )
  SELECT
    ch.CELL_PACKAGE_SK ,
    ch.TREATMENT_SK ,
    ch.TREATMENT_HASH_VAL ,
    chr.RESPONSE_SK ,
    r.CLIENT_OW_ID ,
    r.EVENT_DATE ,
    chr.RESPONSE_CHANNEL_CD ,
    'N' ,
    NULL ,
    TRUNC(r.EVENT_DATE) ,
    ch.RESPONSE_TRACKING_CD ,
    sysdate ,
    r.EVENT_COMMENT ,
    0
  FROM
    SAS_USER.resp_mp_1781661608 r
  INNER JOIN MA_CDM.V_CONTACT ch
  ON
    (
      r.communication_sk = ch.communication_sk
    AND r.CLIENT_OW_ID   = ch.CLIENT_OW_ID
    )
  LEFT JOIN MA_CDM.CI_RESPONSE_CHANNEL_RESPONSE chr
  ON
    (
      ch.CHANNEL_CD                             = chr.RESPONSE_CHANNEL_CD
    AND UPPER(chr.RESPONSE_CHANNEL_RESPONSE_CD) = upper(r.EVENT_TYPE)
    )
  WHERE
    upper(trim(r.EVENT_TYPE)) IN ('OPENED', 'CLICKED', 'SHARED',
    'CLICKED_PARTNER', 'RATED', 'ACCEPTED', 'DECLINED');
COMMIT;
END;
```

When I manually execute this block I have no errors.

Alert.log:

```
<msg time='2016-06-01T02:00:16.643+03:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='rdbms'
 msg_id='3550398128' type='INCIDENT_ERROR' group='Generic Internal Error'
 level='1' host_id='DB-prod-01' host_addr='127.0.0.1'
 prob_key='ORA 600 [kkmupsViewDestFro_4]' upstream_comp='' downstream_comp='SQL_Semantic'
 ecid='' errid='61939' detail_path='/data1/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/sasorcl/sasorcl/trace/sasorcl_ora_1311.trc'>
 <txt>Errors in file /data1/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/sasorcl/sasorcl/trace/sasorcl_ora_1311.trc  (incident=61939):
ORA-00600: internal error code: [kkmupsViewDestFro_4], [24106], [24125], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
 </txt>
</msg>
```

Errors in trace file:

```
========== FRAME [33] (opipls()+11038 -> opiosq0()) ==========
defined by frame pointers 0x7fff8ca41210  and 0x7fff8ca40b20
CALL TYPE: call   ERROR SIGNALED: no   COMPONENT: (null)
```

DB version is 11.2.0.1.0. Probably this error appears because of empty source table (SAS_USER.resp_mp_1781661608). But I can't understand why this code works without errors when manually executed.

Comment: Look on My Oracle Support at bug 9861859 and note 1181833.1, which has some workarounds to try. If that doesn't help you may need to raise a service request.

Comment: Actually there are more bugs, if you search for KKMUPSVIEWDESTFRO_4 in Oracle Support. And you can see this http://michalsimonik.blogspot.de/2015/07/ora-00600-internal-error-code.html

Comment: ORA-600 is an internal error generated by the generic kernel code of the Oracle RDBMS software.ach ORA-600 error comes with a list of arguments They usually enclosed in square brackets and follow the error on the same line for example:
ORA-00600 [14000][51202][1][51200][][]
Each argument has a specific meaning which can only be interpreted by an Oracle support. The arguments may also change meaning from version to version. Possible solution is to apply upgrade patch.